# Where does a New Process reside? In Primary Memory or Secondary Memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, process, operating-system

When a process is selected by a **Long Term Scheduler**, the process enters into **Ready** queue (Ready State from New State) and all the processes in ready queue are present in main memory. But when a process is in a new state, where does it reside? In Primary Memory or Secondary Memory?

But, As Ready Queue processes are stored in Primary Memory, then, New Processes might reside in secondary memory! But couldn't get a proper reason!

Comment: What is "main memory" and "secondary memory"?

Comment: Main memory is a primary memory, which is volatile such as RAM and secondary memory is non volatile like hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process is in the "new" state right after its creation through `fork` system call or something similar, it initially resides on the main memory. Depending on the amount of available memory, the OS may decide to swap it out to secondary storage or keep it in main memory. Refer to the process state transition diagram (taken from The Design of Unix Operating System) below -
[image]

To quote it directly from [The Design of Unix Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) -

> The process enters the state model in the "created" state when the parent process executes the fork system call and eventually moves into a state where it is ready to run (3 or 5). The process scheduler will eventually pick the process to execute, and the process enters the state "kernel running" where it completes its part of the fork system call.

Comment: Got the concept! Does that mean, more the size of main memory, greater the performance?

Comment: Yes  & no. For instance, it won't help to have 16 GB memory on a 32 bit machine.